# EF lookup items being added when they already exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm pretty sure this isn't a duplicate question (or I don't know how to ask it properly) so here goes.  I have an ASP.NET MVC project using EF 6.1.  In it I have an entity called Member.  The Member has a property called Races that can contain one or more Race entities. The Races property on Member:

```
public virtual ICollection<Race> Races { get; set; }
```

The Race entity:

```
 public class Race : ILookupListItem {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
    }
```

The Race entity is what I have always called a lookup.

My issue arises when I try to save the entity after updates have occurred on the client.  My SaveMember controller method is below along with my business logic method for actually saving the entities.  (To avoid any confusion, InjectFrom is the ValueInjecter method and the JSONResponseError and JSONResponseSuccess classes are our custom wrappers around a JsonResult.)

```
public JsonResult SaveMemberInfo(MemberInfoModel model) {
        try {
            // retrieve member
            var member = new Member();
            member.InjectFrom(model);

            var races = new List<Race>();
            races.InjectFromList(model.Races);
            member.Races = races;

            // save member
            var savedMember = _members.UpdateMember(member, out errId);
            var savedModel = GetMemberChartViewModel(savedMember);

            // notify user of success
            return new JsonResponseSuccess(savedModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {                
            return new JsonResponseError(message);
        }
    }
```

The _members.UpdateMember method is below.

```
public Member UpdateMember(Member contract, out int? errId) {
        try {
            using (_db = new ApplicationContext(_currentUserID)) {

                // updates entity state in the context using the entity's State field from Julie Lerman's example on MSDN. 
                _db.FixState();                    
                _db.SaveChanges();

                errId = null;
                return contract;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log error to db and return id
            errId = LogError(ex, "MemberLogic.UpdateMember");
            return null;
        }            
    }
```

When I get the data contract back from the UpdateMember method, the Races property has all the races saved to the memeber before the update, plus any that I just saved (so it's adding but not doing a diff to determine which items were already there and which were removed).  In addition the Races table will now have duplicate entries for the "new" races.  My assumption is that this isn't EF's default behavior but I've never worked with a dropdown list that populated a list of items, usually it's just a single property (like Gender or Country).  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks!

EDIT:  It just occurred to me that the EntityConfiguration for the Member and Race intersection table would be useful, added below.  Obviously, this is only the part I thought to be relevant to the question.

```
        HasMany(t => t.Races).WithMany(t => t.Members).Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("MemberRaces", "dbo");
            m.MapLeftKey("MemberId");
            m.MapRightKey("RaceId");
        });
```

Comment: Try `member.Races.Clear();` then `members.Races.AddRange(races.InjectFromList(model.Races));`

Comment: Since I new it up a few lines before I was assuming it was already empty.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: To clarify: Your `Races` have duplicates in the database?

Comment: After the call to _db.SaveChanges(), yes.